# Any faster/reliable to allocate multiple small blocks rather than 1 big block

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, allocation

I have a program where I allocate multiple buffers as a part of a receive queue to receive messages from a port (UDP protocol). Currently the buffers are not contiguous, but now I am considering making them contiguous so that I can easily patch them together if need be. Is it any less reliable/fast to request 1 large block of memory as opposed to repeatedly allocating smaller blocks.

The total size I'm looking at is 1000 2KB buffers, so 2MB.

And please, don't tell me I should use TCP; if I could I would.

By the way I'm using c++ and compiling with VS2005.

Comment: Hard to come up with a way to make *removing* code a reliability issue.  Code that's not written has guaranteed zero bugs.  Then again, never mess with code that already works.

Comment: It's probably more reliable to get one big request, as long as it's ok that they're all in scope until the same point.

Comment: 1000 2KB buffers = 2048000 bytes, 2MB = 2097152 bytes

Comment: This seems to be a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984434/small-objects-allocator
I would use a proven solution like BOOST.

Comment: @HansPassant I was worried about it being less reliable in the case where the system was tight on RAM and couldn't find a continuous block 2MB long, in which case I thought allocating multiple smaller blocks could be more reliable. I'm not talking about the actual reliability of my code, but the reliability of its operation.

Comment: No, allocating 0.1% of available virtual address space is not a problem you should ever worry about.

Comment: Allocating one big block adds the constraint of continguous memory for all subblocks.This constraint may be a problem with systems/os subject to memory fragmentation. Probably not relevant to your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocating a large block is generally faster than allocating multiple small blocks. Each allocation has an overhead, so with one large allocation you pay the overhead once instead of many times.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely faster to allocate a single large block instead of lots of smaller blocks. However, it also has its own drawbacks. When you allocate small blocks, it is obvious what request owns what block. When you are done, you free the small block.

If you do allocate a large block, you need to implement some sort of allocation scheme to reserve ranges of the large block to your requests, and add them back to the free pool once they are done. So there will be overheads in this area. If you have additional requirements (as you've mentioned, stitching together some requests will require reserving a contiguous area to multiple requests) you will have to implement those features in your custom allocator as well. So you will be adding some level of complexity (and bugs) to your code.

Answer (score 3):

1000 allocations isn't that bad, 1000000 is the number when really ugly overhead comes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    void* bigPtr;
    void* ptrArray[1000];

    clock_t t1, t2, t3;

    t1 = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        ptrArray[i] = malloc(2048);
    }
    t2 = clock();

    bigPtr = malloc(i*2048);

    t3 = clock();

    printf("1 big allocation: %.0f ms, %i small allocations = %.0f ms\n",
        difftime(t3, t2), i, difftime(t2, t1));

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 big allocation: 0 ms, 1000 small allocations = 2 ms
1 big allocation: 0 ms, 10000 small allocations = 9 ms
1 big allocation: 0 ms, 100000 small allocations = 80 ms
1 big allocation: 0 ms, 1000000 small allocations = 733 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly faster, as it will require fewer allocate/free operations. I can't think of any reason it would be more or less reliable, so long as the largest allocation size is well within the limits of your allocator (which 2MB is).

Answer (score 1):

Custom allocators *can* be faster when you have a lot of small objects, for large objects (arrays of small objects should fall into this bucket) it is less likely.  They aren't designed to allocate a lot of small objects.

I am not sure I'd expect buffers of uint8_t to allocate an order of magnitude faster on a custom allocator.

I wouldn't say replacing an allocator could be more reliable.  You're replacing something that is proven to work.

If you have a fixed amount of memory you might just want to preallocate everything, and copy the values in when they come off the line.  I would construe this as a simpler solution to avoiding this bottleneck.

Assuming it is a bottleneck.  You profiled it right?